# Select / copy displayed text content webview javafx

Tags: javascript, javafx, webview

I use a HTML editor to write rich text. 
Later in my program , i use a webview to display this 'rich text'
I want to make a contextmenu that allows the user to select the whole text displayed on the webview , en copy this.
Copying the String itself is a problem because its HTML , not plain text.

I tryed implementing javascript , but im not familiar with that.
I also tryed to use a HTML to plain text converter , jSoup . But it when it converts the HTML it doesnt transver the tabs and spaces correctly.

'''

```
    javafx.scene.control.MenuItem selectAll = new  javafx.scene.control.MenuItem("Select all");
    selectAllCode.setOnAction(e ->
    {

         webViewFitContent.getWebview().getEngine()
                .executeScript(" (selectedText() =function () {   " +
               " var range = document.createRange ();" +
               " + range.setStart (window.getSelection.anchorNode, 0);" +
            " + range.setEnd (window.getSelection.focusNode, 0);" +
            "})()");

        e.consume();
    });
```

'''

Comment: How are you loading the WebEngine? If you already have the file available for editing, can you not just reference that to copy it's contents?

Comment: I tryed using the HTML itself for copying. Problem i have with that is that its in HTML, not plain text that i can copy for use. I tryed using jSoup to convert HTML to plain text , but it messes up the format , spaces and such.

Comment: What do you mean by HTML itself?  Like you're opening the file and reading it line/line or byte/byte? Or you're loading it into a Document and extracting the string contents.  The former is what you need to maintain white space.  Your question says that you are editing the file contents itself, therefore you should have the actual File data used to load the WebEngine?

Comment: if i copy the sourse i get something like <html dir="ltr"><head></head><body contenteditable="true"><p>sdfs<span style="font-weight: bold;">df</span></p><p><span style="font-weight: bold; color: rgb(204, 51, 51);">sdfsdf</span></p></body></html> i need plain text, but with the correct spacing